# Gatsby cloud functions give 404

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-cloud

everyone,

I have a strange issue with Gatsby cloud and gatsby functions.
For a client of mine we run a lot of websites(around 40) on Gatsby cloud. Some of them use Gatsby functions for some integrations. The website's codebase is similar and for some websites Gatsby functions function properly and for some they give 404.

On localhost everything works as it should, but once deployed on Gatsby cloud whichever function I try to hit I get 404. I have compared two website's, one that works and one that doesn't, and I don't see any differences nor in the logic for the functions nor in the configuration.
This started happening recently.
Has anyone ran into this issue with Gatsby cloud functiosn ?